# Reg exp in matlab

Tags: regex, matlab

I'm analyzing a file in matlab and I want to find the number of occurrences of the letter I (capitalized). I'm confused on how to write the regular expression for this step.  Would it be something like `(lines,'.I.')`? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to count the number of capital 'I's in a file, assuming you have read the file in as a string, you could just do this:

```
count = sum(file_string == 'I');
```

If, as in this case, the file is read into a cell-string, one possible way of doing this would be to use:

```
count = sum(strcat(file_cellstr{:}) == 'I');
```

`strcat` will concatenate all of the strings passed to it into a single string. Passing `file_cellstr{:}` to `strcat` is essentially concatenating each of the cells (i.e. each line in your case) into a single string, then searching through it for the letter 'I'. If you wanted to find a whole word, you could use

```
count = length(strfind(strcat(file_cellstr{:}),'word'));
```

If you wanted a regular expression match, you could do the following:

```
count = length(regexp(strcat(file_cellstr{:}),'[a-z]+'));
```

Comment: You could do `length(cell2mat(strfind(file_cellstr,'I')));`

Comment: Or, alternatively, `count = sum(file_cellstr{:} == 'I');`

Comment: `fid=fopen('tweets.txt');
lines = dataread('file', 'tweets.txt', '%s', 'delimiter', '\n');
total=length(lines);
fprintf('Total number of lines: %d \n', total)
length(strfind(lines,'I'))`
This is what I did. It just keeps spitting out the number of lines.

Comment: How about this: `sum(strcat(lines{:}) == 'I')`

Comment: That worked! thanks! what does strcat do? does it just turn a cell to a string basically?

Comment: How could I find just the word "the" without it coming up with other partial matches? I want to just find the whole word "the". I tried what you said `length(strfind(strcat(lines{:}),'the'))` and it matched "further" as well as other words with "the as part of the word.

Comment: In this case, you would use regular expressions, with word boundaries. For instance, `length(regexp(strcat(lines{:}),'\bthe\b'))`.

Comment: I tried this but it gave me an answer of zero when I know for sure its not.

Comment: At this stage, you might be better off asking another question, as this is already fairly off topic from the original question - we're now getting into the specifics of regular expressions, and the comments isn't the right place to be discussing it.

Comment: It can be made even a little more compact if you replace strcat with general concatenation: `sum([C{:}]=='I')` -- Note that the solution to find words may accidentally find two half words or partial words. Also consider using `lower` for a case insensitive search.